# Deleted the .svn folder from SVN checkout folder. Would it impact on the production code directly?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, production-environment, svn-checkout

I have taken the **checkout from SVN** long back ago and didn't do any changes to that folder. After a few months, I saw that folder still on my machine and I tried to delete that folder because it's taking disk memory. SVN **checkout folder** is showing a **green color right-sign tick mark**. I went into that folder and tried to **delete the .svn folder**. Deletion process start and I saw **hundreds of items are deleting per second**. I stopped that deletion process. I **haven't committed anything** after this process.

Would this **deletion process is directly sync-up with the production?** Would it **delete from the production code or server directly?** Would this deletion process **delete the existing runtime application code?** If this deletion directly impacts the **production code** then would it be **recoverable or not**? **How to recover the deleted code** if someone wants to recover it **in the future**?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `.svn` folder altogether. Your working copy is currently useless for Subversion (because it's missing random files) but it's nothing but that, a copy. Subversion is a centralised version control system, master data lives on the repository.

As about production code, it shouldn't have anything to do with Subversion, unless you've built some deployment system that feeds from a working copy or right from a repository. But that'd be out of Subversion's scope.